# Jibx Java.lang.illegalStateException:internalerror- no direct access to class enumAbc

Tags: jibx

I am facing issue while upgrading jibx version 1.3.1 from 1.2.1 for java8

Faceing issue  Jibx :Java.lang.illegalStateException:internalerror- no direct access to a class.

This will happen while doing jibx compile

Could you please suggest some one.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem, but seem to have found a workaround. If you upgrade BCEL (I went with 6.3.1) instead of JiBX (we're on 1.2.3), compilation will go on even for files containing Java8 syntax.

It'd be better to upgrade JiBX, but I wasn't able to get that to work yet so we might just accept this solution.